# CSS table overflows parent div

Tags: html, css

Sorry - I feel this is an old chestnut but the other postings that offer solutions to a table overflowing its parent div don't seem to be helping me.

Below is my HTML and CSS code and I am trying to get the MainBody div to expand with the table data contained in the div navMain.

I'm just about out of ideas and was hoping someone could put be out of my misery.

At the moment the table overflows the MainBody div.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdUuB.png)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800,800italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carter+One');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
.CarterOne {font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;}
.data-table {
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    table-layout:fixed;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.data-table th, .data-table td {
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
   padding: 0px ;
   margin: 0px ;
   background-color: white;
   font-family: "open sans", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#main {
}

#mainTop {
   position: fixed;
   font-size:11pt;
   background-color: #e88732;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #d35400;
   vertical-align: middle;
   color: #404040;
   white-space: nowrap;
   height: 70px;
   width:100%;
   z-index:99;

}

#mainTopLeft {
  padding: 10 5 0 0;
}
#mainTopRight {
   top: 0;
   position: absolute;
   font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 24 0 0 280;
   background-color: #e88732;
   font-size: 12px;
}
#mainTopRight img {
   padding: 0 5 0 10;
   margin: -10 0 0 0 ;
   vertical-align: top;
}
#mainTopRight a {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #262626;
   margin: 0 5 0 5;
   letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}
#mainBody {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 72 0 0 15;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

#bodyNav {
   margin:0 auto;
   padding-left: px;
   height: 90px;
   float:left;

}
#bodyPane  {
   display: inline-block;
   float:left;
   padding-top: 0px;
   background-color: white ;
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px #555;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #555;

    border-radius: 0 4px px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
}

.tabs {
   position: absolute;
   top: 102;
   left: 170;
   width: 1100; /* 1100- stops float wrapping down when window is narrows */
   font-size: 11pt;
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   white-space: nowrap;
}


.tabs li {
 float: left;
    cursor: default;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    height: 32px;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 0 8 0 0;
    padding: 12 2 0 2px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    background: white;
}
.tabs [data-opt]:after  {
   content:attr(data-opt);
}

.tabs li.active {
    z-index: 9 !important;
    color:  #cc0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: white;
    height: 33px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-color: #888;
 }

.tabs li a  { color:inherit; text-decoration: none;}

.tabs img {
     width:22px;
     border: 0;
     cursor:pointer;
     padding: 0 5 2 0;
     border: 0;
     opacity:.4;
     vertical-align:middle;
}

.btnImg, .docsIcon {
     width:22px;
     border: 0;
     cursor:pointer;
     padding: 0 5 2 0;
     border: 0;
     opacity:.4;
     vertical-align:middle;
}



/* SYSTEM MENU SIDEBAR  */
#bodySidebar {
   position: absolute;
   width:140px;
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
   vertical-align: top;
}


.tree,
.tree ul {
  margin:0 0 0 1em; /* indentation */
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  color:#369;
  position:relative;
  font-size:9pt;
  font-weight:normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tree ul {margin-left:.5em} /* (indentation/2) */

.tree:before,
.tree ul:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border-left:1px solid;
}

.tree li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 1.5em; /* indentation + .5em */
  line-height:1.6em; /* default list item's `line-height` */
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.tree  li:hover {
   color: red;
}

.tree li:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:10px; /* same with indentation */
  height:0;
  border-top:1px solid;
  margin-top:-1px; /* border top width */
  position:absolute;
  top:1em; /* (line-height/2) */
  left:0;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  background:white; /* same with body background */
  height:auto;
  top:1em; /* (line-height/2) */
  bottom:0;
}
.tree .selected {
   color:#cc0000;
}
.tree .hover {
   color:#cc0000;
}


 .navSelectorHeading {
   width: 192px;
   height: 35px;
   background-color: #e88732;
   border: 1px solid #e88732;
   color: white;
   font-weight:bold;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin: 0  0 0 0;
   padding: 12 0 0 0;
}

.navTop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 178px;
    left: 210px;
    width:1300;
  font-size:10pt;

}
.navTop ul {
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 8;
    color:#404040;
 }
.navTop li {
 color:#aaaaaa;
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
   padding: 2 18 4 0 ;
   float: left;
}
.navTop li:hover {
    color: #444444;
/*
    border: 1px solid #e88732;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;  */
}
.navTop img:hover {
   opacity:.8;
}
.navtop li.navLiSelected {
   color:  #cc0000;
   font-weight:bold;
}

.navTop img {
     width:22px;
     border: 0;
     cursor:pointer;
     padding: 0 0 0 0;
     margin: 0;
     border: 0;
     opacity:.4;
     vertical-align:middle;
}

.navtop li a  { color:inherit; text-decoration: none;}

.navMain {
   float: top;
    position: absolute;
    left: 210px;
    top: 211px;
    width:100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;

    }



a { text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; }



.body { font-size: 9pt; }
.tbody { font-size: 9pt; }

h1,h2,h3 {
   color: #e88732;
   font-size: 14pt;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 8 0 0 0;
}
h1 {
   font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
h3 {
   font-size: 1.1em;
}


input[type="text"], input[type="password"], select {
  border-radius: 3px;
   background-color:ffffee;
   color: #202020;
}
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button  {
  height: 24px;
  font-size:10pt;
  padding: 0 12 0 12;
  background-color: #e88732;
  border: 1px solid #d35400;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #aaaaaa;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

input[type="radio"]:required {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.85);
}


input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover, button:hover  {
  color: #d35400;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
}

img {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently */
}
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="page_layout_files/main.css" type="text/css">           
            <title>Setup</title>
      </head>
      
      <body height="100%" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">

            <script> document.title='Setup'</script>
            <div id="main">
                  <div id="mainTop">
                        <div id="mainTopLeft">
                        </div>
                        <div id="mainTopRight">
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="mainBody">
                        <div id="bodyNav">
                              <span class="hl1">Setup</span>
                              <span style="padding-left: 55">
                                    <ul class="tabs" width="40">
                                          <li class="active"><a onclick="return frsCheckEditActive(true) " href="#" title="">Organizations </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                              </span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bodyPane">
                              <div class="navSelectorHeading" align="center">Organizational Units
                              </div>



                              <div style="overflow-x:auto;height:550;width:196;">
                                    <ul class="tree"> 
                                          <li onclick="orgSelectorSubmit(frm_oFrmOS2_5_0_0, 1, '1_0_0_0'); return false">Computer Futures</li>
                                          <li onclick="orgSelectorSubmit(frm_oFrmOS2_5_0_0, 1, '4_0_0_0'); return false">David's Templates</li>
                                          <li onclick="orgSelectorSubmit(frm_oFrmOS2_5_0_0, 1, '2_0_0_0'); return false">Pronto Freight Services</li>
                                          <ul></ul>
                                          <li onclick="orgSelectorSubmit(frm_oFrmOS2_5_0_0, 1, '2_8_0_0'); return false">Logistics Department</li>
                                    </ul>
                              </div>
                              <script>
                                    function mainFormSubmit(fn) {
                                          if (!frsCheckEditActive(true)) return false;
                                          f = frm_oFrmOS2_5_0_0;
                                          f.fn.value=fn;
                                          f.submit()
                                                }
                              </script>
                              <div class="navTop">
                                    <ul navtop="">
                                          <li onclick="return mainFormSubmit('od')"><img src="page_layout_files/hrsformdetails.png"> Details </li>
                                    </ul>
                              </div>
                              <div class="navMain" id="navMain">
                                    <table style="height:auto">
                                          <tbody>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>
                                                <tr><td style="background-color:#eee">Row</td></tr>

                                          </tbody>
                                    </table>
                              </div>   
                        </div> 
                  </div>   
            </div>   
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Do you want scroll when overflow inside the <div>???

Comment: No - I am trying to get the page length to expand.

Comment: Could you add your code as a project to the Codepen website? It would make it easier to find a solution.

Comment: https://codepen.io/MartinDay/pen/rmbgPp

Answer (score 0):

`.navMain` uses `position: absolute`, this doesn't takes up space inside it's parent. Change it to `position: relative`.

Comment: Thanks Turqueso, that throws the table data so that it appears way down the page completely outside the parent divs.

Comment: I have continued to struggle with this problem. I have taken Turqueso's suggestion and changed .navMain to position:relative. If I then remove the height:100% from #bodyPane the div expands as I want it to I then have adjusted in .navMain top: -550px; and left: 210px;. This is better but the div container expands to the original length so the div container is 550px larger than I would ideally like. Is this the correct method to use?

Comment: Is a framework an option? something light like skeleton so you can solve basic layout easier?